# Iterate Feature Selection Error -Export grouped features

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, group-layer

I am trying to group values inside my shapefile using Iterate Feature Selection and then Copy selected feature to new shapefile.

[image: Error]

I don't know why but my copy features don't allow me to using %Value% expression. What am i doing wrong?

I am using Arcgis Pro Basic 1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my model structure. I just needed to add collect value at the end of model.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it appears you are writing to the root of your d:\ drive. As you'll be using a Windows OS and probably 8 or 10 you may not have the privileges of writing to that location.

I suggest something like d:\temp  or better still a sub-directory relevant to the project you are working on.

Comment: i've just deleted name of project and database. I running it inside arc database D:\project.gdb\